# How to display code on iPhone using HTML/CSS

Tags: iphone, html, css

The iPhone is admittedly not the best platform for viewing code, but I'd like to optimize the mobile portion of my web site for the device as best I can.  I'm having trouble getting code (Java code, in this case) to display properly.

I'm using `<pre>` tags, along with some CSS to render a nice little background for the code.  This looks OK:

[image]

However if you scroll to see the rest of the code, you get this:

[image]

The text inside the `<pre>` is rendered properly, but the background color stops at the  width of the device.  I have tried this in the simulator, in a 3G device running 3.0, as well as in a 3G running 3.1-beta and they all behave this way.

It **does** render fine in Safari on the Mac; just not on the iPhone.

Here is the HTML:

```
<pre>
String input = readUserInput();  // assume defined elsewhere
int i;

try {
    i = Integer.parseInt(input);
} catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
    System.err.println("You entered an invalid integer: " + exception.getMessage());
}
</pre>
```

And the CSS:

```
pre {
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid green;
    background: #669999;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a curious bug! I'm able to reproduce it on a real live iPhone. I'm guessing it's caused by something about how iPhone processes the [viewport settings](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html). One thing you should clarify is what viewport setting you have in your page (via a meta tag). Your screenshot suggests it's something smaller than the default 980 pixel size. I tried tinkering with the viewport in various ways but couldn't stop this bug from occurring.

I have one workaround, which is to set a width parameter on the pre block. Ie:

```
<pre style="width: 50em;">
```

This is a bad solution for several reasons; it makes a fixed width block, it screws up your border, etc. But it does result in a coloured background block that's wider than the viewport. Maybe it's acceptable to you or maybe it's the basis of a real solution.

Comment: My viewport is set as follows:

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;"/>

Glad to hear that it was reproducable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a width or min-width for your pre block? Or perhaps trying a different position or display attribute for the block.  Could try floating it or display: table.  Just some ideas.

Comment: Yeah I did try hard-coding a width, which worked as a sort of hack, but it had the side effect of causing my font styles in the `<pre/>` tags to get messed up; I would get a weird mix of 11 and 12 pt fonts, where they should all be 11.  Very bizarre.  


and that screws up the fonts for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if pre accepts the overflow attribute but I'd try setting that, if not, wrap it in a div and do the background there, will give you slightly more freedom in your formatting options. (for instance if you wanted to have several blocks of code with "captions" underneath each part)